# PHP convert string to array with variable element length

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match

I have a string `AB0512CD123456` and using preg match how can I convert it to

```
Array[0]='AB';
Array[1]='05';
Array[2]='12CD12';
Array[3]='3456';
```

That is first element with size-2,then 2,6,4 etc.The input string may be dynamic.

Comment: After 2,6,4,X . What is the X ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran the series might not have a progression formula!!

Comment: 2,6,4,etc its really hard sequence... Could you tell us, what number will be next? :D

Comment: @all its for a decoding purpose and not based any sequence,the size is predefined(may be 2,4,2,1,1,6,5,etc)

Comment: dude so the length of the data/string is predefined but your not sure of the length? 2,4,2,1,1,6,5,etc? is that right?

Comment: @Deadpool data/string length might not be predefined,but the 2,4,2,1,1,6,5 etc must be predefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the input string length is fixed, all you need is [`sscanf()`](http://www.php.net/sscanf):

```
var_dump(sscanf('AB0512CD123456', '%2s%2s%6s%4s'));
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "AB"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "05"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "12CD12"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "3456"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use this:

```
    $str="AB0512CD123456";
$Array[0] = substr($str, 0,2);
$Array[1] = substr($str, 2,2);
$Array[2] = substr($str, 4,6);
$Array[3] = substr($str, 10,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Works on any generalized pattern

This example makes use of **`sscanf`** as proposed by [`Paulo Freitas`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222758/paulo-freitas)

```
<?php
$str="AB0512CD123456";
$pattern="2,3,4,5"; // Your pattern
$pattern=explode(",",$pattern);

foreach($pattern as $k=>$v)
{
$newpattern.="%".$v."s";
}
var_dump(sscanf($str,$newpattern));
```